# Read-Only site is "no longer accepting new answers."

Tags: bug, status-completed, read-only

Small note, when the websites are put into read-only mode (for migration purposes), the bottom of the site reads:

> This site is no longer accepting new
>   answers.

Which isn't entirely true. I'm guessing that the read-only part was designed for SE sites that have been shut down for good, but a new user who's just stopping by during the migration might get the wrong idea.

Comment: True, it does seem a bit contradictory to the system message. *Site is read only while we migrate it to a new datacenter. See the blog for details.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed it to

> This site is currently not accepting new answers.

Comment: **RELATED:** [Read-only mode status message, Request to add links to official status pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231126/read-only-mode-status-message-request-to-add-links-to-official-status-pages)