# Planned network maintenance scheduled for Saturday, October 2 at 15:00-17:00 UTC (11:00-13:00 EDT)

Tags: discussion, announcements, maintenance

**NOTE**: 02-OCT-2021 1627Z: Maintenance successfully completed.
**NOTE**: 02-OCT-2021 1500Z: Maintenance is starting.

---

Because we weren't able to accomplish all of the objectives during the last maintenance window ([previous maintenance post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370331/planned-network-maintenance-scheduled-for-friday-october-1-at-0100-0400-utc)), there is another maintenance window scheduled for Saturday, October 2 from 1500Z (11:00 EDT) until 1700Z (13:00 EDT). During this window all Stack Exchange sites will be read-only.

Comment: What are you guys planning on doing anyways? These kinda posts used to be a lot more informative.

Comment: See for example this randomly selected post from searching "planned maintenance": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307744/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-march-17-2018-at-1300-utc-9am-us-eastern

Comment: @Luuklag It's detailed in the linked previous maintenance post.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog you do notice the difference between the post I linked and the sentence "a planned network upgrade", right?

Comment: I understand people are curious about what maintenance needed to be done, but ultimately it doesn’t matter to us users. I don’t see why them spending time explaining in detail what needs to be done is a good way of spending that time. I’d rather have them work on actually useful stuff.