# Review items stats throw an error while loading in read-only mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, review-stats, read-only

Seen during [today's maintenance period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370474/398063) where the sites were in read-only mode.

The review pages were unaccessible (since I was logged out), save for the stats (which do not require one to be logged in). However, while trying to access said stats, a pop-up would appear, saying that "an error occured while loading the review item; please try again". It appeared on all queues, not specific ones.

Nothing blocking, but still sounds like a bug since I couldn't reproduce the issue once the sites were up again.

[image: screenshot of described pop-up]

---

Brave browser 1.27.109, Android 10.

Possibly related to [Navigating to review /stats and /history causes the URL to change to a specific review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369889/398063)? (never encountered it myself, then again I don't remember if I went to the /stats page recently)

Answer (score 5):

We just published a package of fixes for read-only related bugs that included this one. This one in particular was a weird bug, the short version is that we were trying to load a review task even when it wasn't needed, which is what was erroring out. We've made it so review tasks are only loaded where it's used, and also added a new validation for when the website is in read-only mode to avoid future issues with loading review queues.

Thanks for reporting! We appreciate the help and we got some performance boost out of this! :D

Comment: Good news, those bugs are also fixed (same root cause): [Navigating to review /stats and /history causes the URL to change to a specific review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369889/818993), [Checking "Show skipped reviews" takes you out of the review queue history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370832/818993) and [Review stats and history pages URL update to a new review item](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411852/8839059) (this last one was reported on MSO)