# Checking "Show skipped reviews" takes you out of the review queue history

Tags: bug, review, review-history

Currently in the history of some [review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close), if you go to the *My reviews* tab and check the *Show skipped reviews* box you are taken out of the history and to a review item.

I tested this on SO and it happens for me in all review queues. On MSE it only happens in the *Close votes* queue, the functionality works fine in the other 3 review queues.

**Edit:**

RyanM pointed out in the comments this is related to [Navigating to review /stats and /history causes the URL to change to a specific review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369889). The difference being in that post the functionalities can still be reached by clicking (just refresh F5 and back stopped working).

In this case it's a functionality that has in fact become unreachable unless you construct the URL by hand. You can reach the skipped filter by altering the URL from

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/review_item_number?userId=user_number&skipped=true`

to

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history?userId=user_number&skipped=true`

[image]

Using Firefox 93.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro.
rev 2021.10.13.40448

Comment: Sigh. Confirmed on SO. Opera 78

Comment: Almost certainly caused by [Navigating to review /stats and /history causes the URL to change to a specific review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369889/165261), but this is a particularly obnoxious side effect of that.

Comment: @RyanM I suspect the script just attempts to refresh the page, and since the URL is now that of a review task... Ugh.

Comment: @RyanM that post was on the back of my mind and I thought about linking it in the comments. However, the functionalities there reported work (just refresh F5 and back stopped working). In this case it's a functionality that has in fact become unreachable unless you construct the URL by hand.

Comment: I agree this is definitely worth its own bug report, since it's a distinct (and notably worse) problem, even if it's probably the same root cause.  I wouldn't mark it as a dupe, at least.

Comment: Yes, those issues are related. I tested it on SOpt, clicking to show skipped reviews for an empty queue (where the URL is not changed) and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"Show skipped reviews"* functionality is working again after URL bug in the different review pages reported in [Navigating to review /stats and /history causes the URL to change to a specific review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369889) was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).