# There is an error message displayed when clicking on the Calendar icon when "Settings" menu is active

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, preferences, calendar

There is an error message displayed when clicking on the Calendar icon when the [Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) menu is active.
But there is no error message displayed when the "Profile" and "Activity" menus are enabled.

**The error message in plain text:**

> An error occurred when loading days visited history.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Calendar error message]

**404 error found in the browser's Network tab:**

[image: Network tab]

Comment: Reproduced, works on other tabs of the profile though.

Comment: This only happens in some of the subtabs under the Settings tab, not all. I'm able to open the calendar when in the "Edit profile" tab, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed as of Feb 6<sup>th</sup>, 2023.

Calendar should now load on all settings pages.

Comment: The issue reported for the Settings page has been closed, but the issue on the Saves page [The calendar icon is not responding when the Saves menu is active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382690/312043) still exists.

Comment: Ah, thanks for raising. I'll raise that internally and see what I can do

Answer (score 7):

I might have cracked the source of the bug, sadly I can't fix it, however this *should* make fixing it faster. (If I'm not wrong.)

So, when clicking the calendar icon, it sends request to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/daily-site-access/[user-id]`, and replacing the `user-id` with the logged in user id.

However, to find the id, it looks for the active tab link and extracts the id from there. It's best seen in this screenshot:

[image: tabs links with different user id format]

As can be seen above, for the "Profile" and "Activity" tabs, the link format is `/users/[user-id]/...` however the "Settings" tab has a different format, and hence the calendar sends a request to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/daily-site-access/undefined which naturally fails. (404)

Comment: Two userID URL bugs in recent memory [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369889) and [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370832).