# The calendar icon is not responding when the Saves menu is active

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, saves, calendar

On the profile page when the "Saves" menu is selected, clicking on the Calendar icon is not showing the expected result. Instead of that, it is loading infinitely.

Already the same kind of issue was reported for [Settings menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380081/312043)

**GIF for reference:**

[image: Calendar not loading with Saves]

Comment: Hacking in the Developer Console partially fixes it, demonstrating the required fix as well: `$.get('https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/daily-site-access/' + StackExchange.options.user.userId, (d) => $('head').append($(d)))` (the loading image doesn't get removed with my hack, but meh)

Comment: Is [this very similar bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380081/there-is-an-error-message-displayed-when-clicking-on-the-calendar-icon-when-set) fixed? If not, it's dupe. Same root cause, same fix.

Comment: Looks like the same is true of several of the pages under the Settings tab; a few of them work, most of them are forever spinning, and one or two of them show an actual error message. So yeah, I suspect @ShadowTheKidWizard is correct.

Comment: The [duplicate bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380081/there-is-an-error-message-displayed-when-clicking-on-the-calendar-icon-when-set) was fixed, but this bug here was not fixed at the same time. I have reopened this post and added the `status-review` tag

Comment: @Connell almost year later, any updates on this?

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Many, many days later, finally got a chance to look into this! I have a fix in the works and I'll write up an answer once I have it shipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this! The fix will be in production either today or Monday.

Here's what happened: basically, we implemented the Saves tab differently than the other tabs - with its own lil typescript file. Unfortunately the calendar js lives in a large old other .js file, so the Saves tab wasn't using it at all. A little confusing to figure out but a super easy fix otherwise.

Thanks for the bug report! Please let me know if there's anything still amiss after Monday.

Comment: I suspect that the fix here [broke something else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398206/changing-the-sort-order-in-the-saves-tab-does-not-update-the-view), can you please look into it?

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda yup - it looks like this is probably related, I will look into it today.