# Visited Calendar pop out on user activity pages missing

Tags: bug, status-review, profile-page, visited-days, calendar

**Update Jan. 17, 2024** Yay!  The calendar pop-out is back in action.

When I click the link on "Visited xxx days" (hover text:Click to view daily visit calendar) on [user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) I get only a clocking display, no calendar.

> [image]

This seems identical to an old issue, [Visited Calendar Doesn't Render](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71873/visited-calendar-doesnt-render) from 2010, and it occurs on all my Activity pages that I checked.

Comment: Reproduced on macOS 13.5, using: Chrome 116, Edge 116, Firefox 116, Opera 102, Safari 16.6

Comment: @ElementsinSpace: Thanks!  My browser is Chromium 116 on  (desktop) Fedora Workstation 38.  Also under Edge 116 on MS Windows 10.

Comment: On MSO: [Stack Overflow console error when clicking calendar view for daily visits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426239)

Comment: Repro'd. Same bug.

Comment: @V2Blast For bugs like this where you can reproduce the issue, please consider adding a [meta-tag:status-review] tag.

Comment: @Makyen: The linked MSO post was already on our radar, so there isn't really a benefit from our end to adding the tag to both versions of the post. I've linked the Jira issue for this post to the existing issue for the MSO post.

Comment: As a workaround, based on [the answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392883/271271) by [InSync](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1341484/insync) you can execute `delete $.ui` in the browser console *prior to trying to open the calendar* and have the calendar displayed normally.

Comment: @Makyen:  I'm able to get this to work (and display the calendar), but it seems only to apply to the immediate Activity page (not to all Communities where I visit).

Comment: @hardmath Yes, it will only apply to the current page. In a browser, each page visit is completely separate. The context in which the JavaScript is running is completely destroyed when you navigate away from the page. A new execution context is created when the new page starts loading. I was only offering a very temporary solution for a relatively rarely used feature. It is possible to create a userscript which is then loaded into every appropriate page and makes the correction automatically each time, which would be more appropriate if it's a feature that's often used or SE delays fixing.

Comment: I see your update. But still, the issue exists in the ["Saves"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/saves/current/all) menu. [The calendar icon is not responding when the Saves menu is active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382690/312043)

Comment: @Arulkumar:  Good catch.  Yes, the problem persists on the Saves menu tab, although it seems fixed for Settings/Preferences tab of user page.  I only checked for this on Meta SE however.

Answer (score 18):

The culprit is the following function:

```js
StackExchange.loadJqueryUi = function() {
    var cssLink = StackExchange.settings.paths.jQueryUICSSPath
      , jsLink = StackExchange.settings.paths.jQueryUIJSPath;
    if ($.ui)
        return $.Deferred().resolve();
    /* Some AJAX loader code... */
}
```

...which was called by:

```js
$(function() {
    StackExchange.loadJqueryUi().done(showCalendar);
});

function showCalendar() {
    var $cal = $('.js-daily-access-calendar');
    
    $cal.datepicker({ /* Options... */ });
}
```

`StackExchange.loadJqueryUi` assumes that `$.ui` exists also means `$.datepicker()` is available, which was not the case. I tried two crude monkeypatches; they both worked:

```js
StackExchange._loadJqueryUi = StackExchange.loadJqueryUi
StackExchange.loadJqueryUi = function() {
  delete $.ui;
  return StackExchange._loadJqueryUi();
}
```

```js
StackExchange.loadJqueryUi = function() {
    var cssLink = StackExchange.settings.paths.jQueryUICSSPath
      , jsLink = StackExchange.settings.paths.jQueryUIJSPath;
    if ($.datepicker)
        return $.Deferred().resolve();
    /* The rest... */
}
```

TLDR: Run `delete $.ui` in your browser console.

Whether they break anything and how jQueryUI was loaded without `.datepicker()` in the first place are unknown. I didn't bother to check further, since all I want was to see my SO visit calendar. Isn't she beautiful?

[image: Visited 189 days, 182 consecutive]

Comment: I put a small bounty on this Question to encourage a revised Answer that explains how the problem was fixed.  You seem to have the skills to spot what changed a few days ago.

Comment: @hardmath I don't; I'm not a SE staffer and therefore have no idea whatsoever about how they changed their code (I didn't even notice that the bug was fixed until I got this notification). That said, I'm expecting them to write their own answer.

Answer (score 7):

If it helps, I can reproduce this on MSE with a computer running Windows 10 22H2. My browser version is Firefox 116.0.3 (64-bit).

Here's what I get in the browser console, if it helps (on AU):

```
Uncaught TypeError: $cal.datepicker is not a function
    jQuery 14
    success https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/user.en.js?v=9b38ac467cb4:1
    jQuery 6
    init https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/user.en.js?v=9b38ac467cb4:1
    jQuery 9
    init https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/user.en.js?v=9b38ac467cb4:1
    <anonymous> https://askubuntu.com/users/1438484/cocomac:40
    jQuery 3
    init https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    h https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    jQuery 3
    c https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    jQuery 2
    c https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    t https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    jQuery 3
    onreadystatechange https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    d https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    u https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    s https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    p https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    p https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    s https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    h https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    init https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d9f62851ed:1
    jQuery 8
```

Comment: If you are motivated to dig further, I posted a small bounty on this Question to encourage someone to explain how the fix was made a few days ago.  Thanks for your earlier investigation!