# Date picker is broken with uncaught `TypeError`, spins forever

Tags: bug, profile-page, calendar

The date picker widget on the user profile page is broken. Attempting to click on it has it spin forever. The JavaScript console has the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $cal.datepicker is not a function
```

Erroring JavaScript function...

```js
function showCalendar() {
        var $cal = $('.js-daily-access-calendar');
        
        $cal.datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var y = date.getFullYear();
                var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
                var d = date.getDate();
                var hasVisited = visited[y] && visited[y][m] && visited[y][m][d];
                return [false, (hasVisited ? 'ui-state-active' : ''), (y + '-' + m + '-' + d)];
            }
        });
    }
```

[image: StackOverflow date picker widget spinning forever, no freehand circles]

I'm using Firefox Dev Edition 119.0b4 on Windows.

Comment: Already reported and marked as under review: [Visited Calendar pop out on user activity pages missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392624/visited-calendar-pop-out-on-user-activity-pages-missing)

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that question when I tried to search for it. Closed :)

Comment: Yeah, different wording. That's why keeping duplicates is good, now it will be easier for the next person going to report the bug to find it's already reported.