# Consecutive Days Calendar in Profile throwing an jQuery UI Error

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, profile-page

Do we have a fix for the Calendar that is displayed in own User Profile for the consecutive days?

[image: error]

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Sign in to Stack Overflow.
2. Go to User Profile.
3. Click on "Visited XXX days, XXX consecutive"

Expected Result: Calendar should show up.

Current Behaviour: Throws an error.

Comment: Duplicate: [Visited Calendar pop out on user activity pages missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392624/visited-calendar-pop-out-on-user-activity-pages-missing)

Comment: Thanks @ElementsInSpace