# Missing hyphen in "read-only mode" when browsing a post in read-only mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammar, read-only

Seen during [yesterday's maintenance period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370474/398063) where the sites were in read-only mode.

While the network-wide banner, general communication, and hyphen rules (that I know of) mandate the spelling "read-only", the hyphen is missing in the placeholder text located where the answer box usually is:

[image: missing hyphen in placeholder text]

Compare with the banner:

[image: banner using a hyphen]

---

Brave browser 1.27.109, Android 10. (although I strongly doubt this has anything to do with it)

Answer (score 3):

We just published a package of fixes for read-only related bugs that included this one. I went through the code looking for any references to read-only that looked wrong and fixed it! It will be reflected whenever the site goes into maintenance mode again.

Thanks for reporting! We appreciate the help.

Comment: Mh, is it though? [This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqldo.png) taken today still does not have a hyphen. Mobile view, dunno if that has any influence

Comment: @Jenayah thanks for reporting this! After seeing some screenshots we went down an internal search of why the changes didn't seem to be there. Turns out we had a problem with our Secondary build, and that's where we were running off from last weekend. A build will be triggered tonight and should fix the issue for the next time we run off of Secondary. Appreciate the help!